# Batches or chunk insert with PDO in php

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a script that results in some basic inserts, using PDO between MySQL and DB2.

The script works perfectly but I have hundreds of thousands of records to insert so I'd like to do something like batch inserts or something. Basically something where I can keep the speed as high as possible but do them in batches so I don't time out or have memory issues in powershell on the server.

Here's the working portion that does the ultimate insert:

```
$insert = $MysqlConn->prepare($tempInsert);

while($row2 = $place->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    print_r($row2);

    $values = [
        ":DEALER" => $row2["DEALER"],
        ":SHIPDATE" => $row2["SHIPDATE"],
        ":QUANTITY" => $row2["QUANTITY"],
        ":INVOICE" => $row2["INVOICE"],
        ":FRAME" => $row2["FRAME"],
        ":COVER" => $row2["COVER"],
        ":COLOR" => $row2["COLOR"],
    ];

    try{
        $insertRslt = $insert->execute($values);
    }catch(PDOException $ex){
        echo "QUERY FAILED!!!: " . $ex->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Is there a pretty straight forward way I can do something like this without much refactoring?

Comment: You might like my presentation [Load Data Fast!](https://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/load-data-fast)

Comment: The two things are not mutually exclusive.  Speed and Running out of memory.  Often making better use of memory, requires more running time.  I've found you often cannot have both.  Time limits being the easier to deal with, once you are out of memory you are done.  But you can make a script run for a very long time.  PS I've migrated upwards of 100 million rows from MySql to Mongo, took several days but it worked with no memory issues.